# Why does my collection view header 'flash' white when I insert an item into its section? Any way to prevent this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I have a collection view with both a header and footer. When I insert an item into the collection view using insertItemsAtIndexPaths, the header 'flashes' white, almost as if its reloading. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Yes, I've got this too. Very annoying, I haven't found a fix but I'll keep an eye on this question.

Comment: As much as I hate to admit defeat, i'm considering having the header as a cell instead, or a cell in another section. Not a particularly nice solution though.