# ios7 table section header title is flashing white when reloading section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having a problem with UITableView section animations very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456993/why-does-my-collection-view-header-flash-white-when-i-insert-an-item-into-its).  Unfortunately, no one seems to have found an answer for this.

I have a table view with multiple sections that expand and close when the first cell in each section is selected.  There no adding or removing of cell, just collapsing and expanding the section.

My problem is that the sections' header titles are flashing white momentarily before returning to normal, whenever the following method is used.

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Only the title of the section being collapsed is flashing white though.  Has anyone else had this problem or found a solution?

I'm using this same design in another table where this is not an issue.  One thing to note here though, is that my cells are a custom subclass of the UITableCell and are larger than the first cell that is used to collapse the section.

Maybe something about ios laying out the cells on section animation is making the section header title flash white?

I can post a code example it it'll help.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Xcode. Read the tag's description.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  I should have read the tag description before adding it.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, only when using "reloadSections". If I use reloadData on the table then there is no issue.